# Convert Epoch seconds to date and time format in Java

Tags: java, datetime-format, epoch, seconds

I have seconds since 1970 january 1 UTC (Epoch time).

```
1320105600
```

I need to convert that seconds into date and time in below format.

```
Friday,November 4,2011 5:00,AM
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: One idea would be to browse the javadocs - for example java.util.Date

Answer (score 53):

In case you're restricted to legacy `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` APIs, you need to take into account that the timestamps are interpreted in milliseconds, not seconds. So you first need to multiply it by 1000 to get the timestamp in milliseconds.

```
long seconds = 1320105600;
long millis = seconds * 1000;
```

This way you can feed it to a.o. the constructor of [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and finally use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to convert a `java.util.Date` to `java.lang.String` in the desired date format pattern, if necessary with a predefined time zone (otherwise it would use the system [default time zone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault--), which is not GMT/UTC per se and thus the formatted time might be off).

```
Date date = new Date(millis);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE,MMMM d,yyyy h:mm,a", Locale.ENGLISH);
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println(formattedDate); // Tuesday,November 1,2011 12:00,AM
```

In case you're already on Java8, there's a [`LocalDateTime#ofEpochSecond()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#ofEpochSecond-long-int-java.time.ZoneOffset-) which allows you to feed epoch seconds directly without the need for multiplying into milliseconds flavor.

```
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(seconds, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC);
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE,MMMM d,yyyy h:mm,a", Locale.ENGLISH);
String formattedDate = dateTime.format(formatter);
System.out.println(formattedDate); // Tuesday,November 1,2011 12:00,AM
```

Comment: Actually i made a mistake to post the question clearly.Here iam working with US chicago timings.And my seconds are 1320105600.The correct result for this question is Tuesday,November 0l,2011 7:00 AM but iam getting Monday,October 31,2011 7:00,PM by using the above code.

Comment: I understand that there's a timezone difference, but 12 hours?

Comment: I verified it once again for Chicago time (CST, GMT-6). Your comparison material is likely wrong or misinterpreted. Perhaps the AM/PM marker or 24 hour time information was not properly been interpreted. The exact 12-hour difference is also a too big coincidence. Note that the answer which you got on your [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263148/how-to-find-seconds-since-1970-in-java) also confirms this. Try it with `CST` as timezone and `calendar.set(2011, Calendar.OCTOBER, 31, 19, 0);`. You'll get exactly `1320105600`.

Comment: It seems that you or your colleague still didn't understand the timezone influence: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273200/code-to-convert-seconds-to-date-and-time-combination-in-java This also confirms that your comparison material is wrong. I'll edit the answer to include the UTC timezone.

Answer (score 20):

```
long yourSeconds = 1320105600L;
Date date = new Date(yourSeconds * 1000);
```

See this [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28long%29) for more info. The constructor needs milliseconds.

To display this date in an appropriate format you should check [DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html)

Here is an example:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz");
System.out.println(df.format(date));
```

Answer (score 12):

## java.time

The [Answer by BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8262366/642706) is good in that it points you to using java.time. But that Answer uses [`LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) where [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is more appropriate. A [`LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) is *not* a moment on the timeline as it purposely has no concept of [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offset_from_UTC) or [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone).

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`. The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) team also advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

## `Instant`

A moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution up to [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) is represented by the [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond ( 1_320_105_600L );
```

Dump to console. Your input value is the first moment of November 1, 2011 in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). The `Z` on the end, short for 'Zulu', means UTC.

```
System.out.println ( "instant: " + instant );
```

> instant: 2011-11-01T00:00:00Z

## `ZonedDateTime`

In your comments you mention wanting to see this date-time through the lens of the [`America/Chicago`](http://time.is/Chicago) time zone. Use a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). Apply a time zone, `ZoneId`, to get a `ZonedDateTime` object. We see that Chicago is five hours behind UTC on that date.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of ( "America/Chicago" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone ( zoneId );
```

> zdt: 2011-10-31T19:00-05:00[America/Chicago]

## Strings

The Strings seen above are in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. To generate strings in other formats, use the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class. You can specify your own custom pattern. But generally best to let java.time automatically localize to the human language and cultural norms encoded in a [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) object.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime ( FormatStyle.FULL );
formatter = formatter.withLocale ( Locale.US );
String output = zdt.format ( formatter );
```

> Monday, October 31, 2011 7:00:00 PM CDT

To specify your own custom format, search Stack Overflow for many examples and more discussion.

Answer (score 2):

```
int seconds = 1320105600;
Date date = new Date(seconds * 1000);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE,MMMM d,yyyy h:mm,a");
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use `java.util.Date` and `java.text.DateFormat` to get the format you want. You can look up how to do it in [tutorials on the Web](http://javatechniques.com/blog/dateformat-and-simpledateformat-examples/).