# how to find seconds since 1970 in java

Tags: java

iam working with a real time project where i got a requirement to find seconds since 1970 january 1.I have used the following code to find out seconds but is giving wrong result.The code is as follows.

```
public long returnSeconds(int year, int month, int date) {
    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar1.set(1970, 01, 01);
    calendar2.set(year, month, date);
    long milliseconds1 = calendar1.getTimeInMillis();
    long milliseconds2 = calendar2.getTimeInMillis();
    long diff = milliseconds2 - milliseconds1;
    long seconds = diff / 1000;
    return seconds;
}
```

In the above in place of `year,month,date` I'm passing `2011,10,1` and iam getting

```
1317510000
```

but the correct answer is

```
1317427200
```

Any help regarding this is very useful to me.

Comment: `getTimeInMillis()` *already* measures from the Unix epoch (1970 etc etc).  If you look at milliseconds1 it should be zero (unless you're  getting timezone problems).  So taking the difference is unnecessary

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Based on your desire that `1317427200` be the output, there are several layers of issue to address.

- First as others have mentioned, java already uses a UTC 1/1/1970 epoch.  There is normally no need to calculate the epoch and perform subtraction unless you have weird locale rules.
- Second, when you create a new Calendar it's initialized to 'now' so it includes the time of day.  Changing the year/month/day doesn't affect the time of day fields.  So if you want it to represent midnight of the date, you need to zero out the calendar before you set the date.
- Third, you haven't specified how you're supposed to handle time zones.  Daylight Savings can cause differences in the absolute number of seconds represented by a particular calendar-on-the-wall-date, depending on where your JVM is running.  Since epoch is in UTC, we probably want to work in UTC times?  You may need to seek clarification from the makers of the system you're interfacing with.
- Fourth, months in Java are zero indexed.  January is 0, October is 9.

Putting all that together

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
calendar.clear();
calendar.set(2011, Calendar.OCTOBER, 1);
long secondsSinceEpoch = calendar.getTimeInMillis() / 1000L;
```

that will give you `1317427200`

Comment: my date and time is "19 Sep 2062 02:30:00" and i want to get "-2147483648" but i don't get. My current result is "2925858600".

Comment: @Varun Patel For a negative number one expects the date would be in 1962, not 2062.....

Answer (score 76):

The methods [`Calendar.getTimeInMillis()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis%28%29) and [`Date.getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29) both return milliseconds since 1.1.1970.

For current time, you can use:

```
long seconds = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000l;
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to know the milliseconds since epoch to a specific time, not necessarily to "now".

Comment: Is there a Calendar.getTimeInMillis()? I thought it was `Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()`.

Comment: why did you devide by 10001?

Comment: @bubakazouba thats 1000L, 1000 as long.

Answer (score 70):

Since Java8:

```
java.time.Instant.now().getEpochSecond()
```

Comment: Verified that this is in UTC (which is what I was looking for). Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

It's **[Date.getTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29)**.

Comment: Actually `Date.getTime()` returns amount of **milli**seconds, not seconds. To get seconds call `Date.getTime() / 1000`.

Answer (score 5):

The difference you see is most likely because **you don't zero** the hour, minute, second and milliseconds fields of your `Calendar` instances: `Calendar.getInstance()` gives you the current **date and time**, just like `new Date()` or `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Note that the [month field of Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH) is **zero-based**, i.e. January is 0, not 1.

Also, don't prefix numbers with zero, this might look nice and it even works till you reach 8: `08` isn't a valid numeral in Java. Prefixing numerals with zero makes the compiler assume you're defining them as octal numerals which only works up to `07` (for single digits).

Just drop `calendar1` completely (1970-01-01 00:00:00'000 is the begin of the epoch, i.e. zero anyway) and do this:

```
public long returnSeconds(int year, int month, int date) {
    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(year, month, date, 0, 0, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    return cal.getTimeInMillis() / 1000;
}
```

Comment: This looks the only complete answer to the problem.. wondering why no one noticed it. Correct implementation, same method signature as requested.

Answer (score 4):

The answer you want, "1317427200", is achieved if your reference months are January and October. If so, the dates you are looking for are 1970-JAN-01 and 2011-OCT-01, correct?

Then the problem are these numbers you are using for your months.

See, if you check the Calendar API documentation or even the constants provided in there ("Calendar.JANUARY", "Calendar.FEBRUARY" and so on), you'll discover that months start at 0 (being January).

So checking your code, you are passing february and november, which would result in "1317510000".

Best regards.

Comment: oh.. iam treating january as 1 that is why i got wrong answer, any way i got the answer.You are correct.Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

## java.time

Using the [`java.time`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;

int year = 2011;
int month = 10;
int day = 1;
int date = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);

date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toEpochSecond; # Long = 1317427200
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the `TimeUtils` utility method:

```
TimeUtils.millisToUnit(System.currentTimeMillis(), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```