# Code to convert seconds to Date and time combination in java

Tags: java

I have seconds like below:

`1320130800`

I need to convert the value into Date and Time Combination format.  While formatting I got the result as follows:

`Tuesday,November 1,2011 2:00,AM`

But the correct result is as follows:

`Tuesday,November 1,2011 7:00,AM`

For the above format conversion I used the below code:

```
 long millis = 1320130800*1000;
           Date date = new Date(millis);
           SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE,MMMM d,yyyy h:mm a");
           String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
           System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Can any one guide me to get the correct answer?

Comment: Looks like the date formatting time zone issue.

Comment: I am guessing your time zone is out by 5 hours. Are you in India by any chance? ;)

Comment: Is this you or your colleague? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262333/how-to-convert-seconds-into-date-and-time-format-in-java

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like it's just a time zone issue - you need to set the time zone for the formatter:

```
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

(Note that in your sample code, `long millis = 1320130800*1000;` doesn't work as it performs the multiplication in 32-bit arithmetic; you need something like `long millis = 1320130800L*1000;`.)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Calendar API instead.

After you have the Date object, construct a Calendar object (getInstance() returns one with the default Time Zone) and do setDate(Date) on it and parse it like that.

Alternatively, you can take a look at Joda Time APIs since they are easy to use.

Regards!

Comment: He's formatting, not parsing - and `DateFormat` always takes a Date, not a `Calendar`. Joda Time is an admirable suggestion if there's anything more going on date/time-wise though.

Comment: Fair enough! I assumed he is just showing the formatted Date, just so we can observe that it is not storing the correct date or hour to be more precise. Regards!