# Parse timestamp into LocalDateTime Scala

Tags: scala, datetime, date-formatting

I have a dataset for my User case class with the date of birth field.  I want to put this data into my database, however, the date is represented in a form of the date stamp, so I do not know how to parse it using LocalDateTime. 
Here are the examples of the datestamps I have:

```
-631065600
885254400
48124800
-1007596800
```

And I tried to do something like this:

```
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("n")

  val users = List(
    models.User(1, "sosodachenheonne@list.me", "Роман", "Терленчан", "m", LocalDateTime.parse("885254400", formatter)),
    models.User(2, "vyhihhimrusedac@list.me", "Артём", "Пенленный", "m", LocalDateTime.parse("48124800", formatter)),
    models.User(3, "istoordadanaihdut@gmail.com", "Борислав", "Фетленвич", "m", LocalDateTime.parse("-1007596800", formatter))
  )
```

But I've got such an exception:

```
java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {NanoOfSecond=885254400},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed
```

Comment: why did you use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("n")`?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I may understand it wrong, but I used it to set the formatting of date in nanoseconds

Comment: You do not want `LocalDateTime` here as that class purposely lacks any time zone or offset-from-UTC information. Instead, convert your count-from-epoch number to an `Instant` and from there perhaps to a `ZonedDateTime`. Search Stack Overflow for many examples.

Comment: If only the date of birth is of interest (not the hour of day), I suggest you convert to `LocalDate` in the end.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Epoch seconds to date and time format in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262333/convert-epoch-seconds-to-date-and-time-format-in-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert your variables from a timestamp to a LocalDateTime like this: `LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(885254400), ZoneOffset.UTC)`

Comment: Good answer. I think the numbers in the questions are seconds since the epoch, not milliseconds, so you want `.ofEpochSecond(885254400)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
  val fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy")
  val date = new Date(-631065600)
  println(LocalDateTime.parse(date.toString, fmt))
```

Comment: I get such exception for conversion of this number: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '1969-12-24' could not be parsed at index 0

Comment: Probably you use java.sql.Date which produces string representation in another format. Use java.util.Date instead.

Comment: Or have a look at my answer ;)

Comment: When you can use the modern Java date and time API (`java.time`, for example `LocalDateTime`), you certainly do not want to use neither `java.util.Date` nor `java.sql.Date`. Those classes are long outdated.