# Convert Unix epoch time

Tags: java

I am trying to convert Unix epoch time to an ISO 8601 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) with the time zone. I have it working but only if it's local time.  How can I pass in the time zone as an offset?

Input 1: `1483772400000`

Input 2: `-0700`    (but I can convert as needed)

Desired output:  `2017-01-07T00:00:00-07:00` or simply `2017-01-07T00:00:00-07`

Current output:  `2017-01-06 23:00:00-08` as I'm in PST

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA, JDK 1.8u202 .

```java
    package util.date;
    
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.Locale;
    import java.util.TimeZone;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    
    public class EpochToISO {
        public String epochToIso8601(long time) {
            String format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssX";
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.getDefault());
            sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
            return sdf.format(new Date(time));
        }
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            EpochToISO convert = new EpochToISO();
            long epoch = 1483772400000; // Example
            String iso8601 = convert.epochToIso8601(epoch);
            System.out.println(epoch + " -> " + iso8601);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please consider adding the `time` tag. It may attract users better suited to your problem and better describes your problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ISO8601 format in java given seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48039785/iso8601-format-in-java-given-seconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TimeZone.getDefault()` is used to get the `TimeZone` of host machine on which code is executed on. You can provide the TimeZone for which you want to obtain the datetime. Ex:

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Creston"); 
sdf.setTimeZone(timeZone);
```

TimeZones with GMT/UTC Offsets https://code2care.org/pages/java-timezone-list-utc-gmt-offset