# Wrong Date Format shown in device from JSON API

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat, epoch

I was showing my JSON date in activity layout but it gives me this kind of date format "1547458358000". How to change the date format into YYYY-MM-dd k:mm:s?

The appAdded is date came from JSON API.

From the result of testing. 
The toast message I received is API TIME shows as 1547458358000 while outDatedAPI shown as null.

```
 try {
    SimpleDateFormat DateformatAPKAPIInstalled = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd k:mm:s");
        APITime = DateformatAPKAPIInstalled.parse(appAdded);
        SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd k:mm:s");
         outputDateAPI = outputFormat.format(APITime);
        Toast.makeText(FirstPageActivity.this, "DATE KO" dateAPKUpdated + appAdded + APITime, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: that is timestamp you need to convert it to appropriate date.

Comment: enlighten me for the mistake I made in code instead of giving negative feedback. thankyou.

Comment: "1547458358000" seems to be the milliseconds since midnight on 1 Jan 1970.

Comment: @KaranMer how to convert to appropriate date?

Comment: Do a google search for converting time stamp to date for the enlightment

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert timestamp in milliseconds to string formatted time in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142313/convert-timestamp-in-milliseconds-to-string-formatted-time-in-java). Or more precisely duplicate of [Convert Epoch seconds to date and time format in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262333/convert-epoch-seconds-to-date-and-time-format-in-java).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass long timestamp and can convert it to date using below code

```
private String getDate(long time) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    cal.setTimeInMillis(time);
    String date = DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd", cal).toString();
    return date;
}
```

Comment: thank you, I use this also as a reference and modify some code to solve my problem