# how to print numeric value to DateTime format in java

Tags: java, datetime-format, datetime-conversion

### Easy in PHP but how will it be in Java.

```
$value="1562916792";
echo date("Y-m-d h:i:sa", $values['time']);
```

output: 2019-07-12 01:03:12pm

Comment: I guess it depends on where you get your *"numeric value."* What does the numeric value represent?

Comment: @Zephyr It's seconds since epoch (1/1/1970).

Comment: In the linked question I recommend [the knowledgeable answer by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38547492/5772882). Only he assumes America/Chicago rather than America/Denver time zone, but I think you can change that.

Answer (score 1):

To get that time, I'll assume you are in India time zone, in which case you do it like this:

*Using Java 8 Time API*

```
int value = 1562916792;
System.out.println(Instant.ofEpochSecond(value)
                          .atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")) // or ZoneId.systemDefault()
                          .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd hh:mm:ssa")));
```

*Using old Java Date API*

```
int value = 1562916792;
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ssa").format(value * 1000L));
```

*Output*

```
2019-07-12 01:03:12PM
```

Comment: Agree, the desired output would agree with Sri Lanka or Inida time zone (Asia/Colombo or Asia/Kolkata).